# How to get RestTemplate connection timeout property value?

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

We are using spring [RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) in our project for making API call, we are configuring timeout properties using `RestTemplateBuilder`, but is there a way to get these property values after constructing `RestTemplate`

```
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplateWithConnectReadTimeout() {  
return new RestTemplateBuilder()
    .setConnectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(TIMEOUT))
    .setReadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(TIMEOUT))
    .build();
}
```

Comment: it is stored at RequestFactoryCustomizer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/client/RestTemplateBuilder.java#L421 and it seems very private, reflection can be the last way, again i do not know what else are the possibillity.